# How to cut a space from a string in a Unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am reading a file and cutting a column based on some logic. My issue is I am not able to cut a column with space.

This is the code for testing -

```
st="1|alalhabad|up|tushar|kesarwani|90|   mls   k|19990|india|420|24|m"
HardErrorCheckColumnValue=`echo $st | cut -d'|' -f7`
echo $HardErrorCheckColumnValue
```

The output should be -

```
   mls   k
```

But I am getting-

```
mls   k
```

How do I make it not trim the leading or trailing spaces? It should give space, even if it contains only space.

Comment: you mean *leading* space, right?

Comment: Please use `$(…)` rather than back-ticks.  And use double quotes around variables when spaces matter.  Also, I don't think your output would include more than one space between the `s` and the `k` — not based on the script you show.

Comment: Thanks for $(..) . New to unix.. So i did not know it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use quotes around your variables:

```
HardErrorCheckColumnValue=$(echo "$st" | cut -d'|' -f7)
echo "$HardErrorCheckColumnValue"
   mls   k
```

Better to use `$(...)` instead of old fashioned back-tick for command substitution.

Comment: I am new here and need 15 Reps to do that. Will definitely do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

awk Will help you with that

```
$ cat file.dat
1|alalhabad|up|tushar|kesarwani|90|  mls ki |19990|india|420|24|m

$ awk -F"|" '{print "|"$7"|"}' file.dat
|  mls ki |
||
```

**EDIT 2**

If you echo the st variable there is a problem there, where some spaces disapear:

check the difference:

```
$ st="1|alalhabad|up|tushar|kesarwani|90|   mls   k|19990|india|420|24|m"

$ echo $st
1|alalhabad|up|tushar|kesarwani|90| mls k|19990|india|420|24|m  <-- ONE SPACE GONE

$ cat file.dat
1|alalhabad|up|tushar|kesarwani|90|  mls ki |19990|india|420|24|m

$ awk -F"|" '{print "|"$7"|"}' file.dat
|  mls ki |  <---- SPACE OK
||
```

Comment: the damage is the echo.... but it´s talking about trimming all the spaces... please try it...

Comment: Mac-mini-de-Alejandro:~ ouchito$ awk -F"|" '{print "|"$7"|"}' file.dat
|  mls ki |
||

Comment: Or `echo "$st"` works (when you have `st="1|alalhabad|up|tushar|kesarwani|90|   mls   k   |19990|india|420|24|m"`) — the key thing is that the `echo` must not be given a chance to screw up the spacing. (Oh, and Markdown in comments removes multiple spaces even in code snippets, which is appalling but life is unfair sometimes.)

Comment: **i personally dont like the echo there... that´s why I tried different ways (with the file) and saw the difference.. Sorry for the format, I didn´t care i wrote the two different and then the spaces where not ok as result

Answer (score -1):

Protect your variable before printing it:

```
echo "$HardErrorCheckColumnValue"
```

Without the quote it gets expanded to `echo    mls   k`, while with it get's expanded to `echo "   mls   k"`

*But as pointed out @Mat, damage already done. So refer to @anubhava answer :)*

Comment: Not sufficient here, damage has already been done before that line.

Comment: Yes... @Anubhava 's answer works well for me. So Double Quotes is must when space matters. Great